# loading content from other webpages into div and adding styling

Tags: jquery, ruby, ajax, iframe, nokogiri

I'm trying to create a site for personal use that displays certain presidential election polls in one location. I thought I would be able to do this with an iframe and simply add `display: none` to the parts I do not want but it looks like its not possible to override the external css styles in an iframe.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might accomplish this? I've been looking into nokogiri and AJAX however I have not yet been successful. With nokogiri I was able to pull the information from the site however I'm not sure how to actually display it in the the HTML on mine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it cannot be done, per @kabrice - In fact, iframe is an html element and a formalised specification defined by the W3C (w3.org/TR/html-markup/iframe.html) . and in the W3C documentation, we can read that iframe is a nested browsing context (w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html) just a little bit like browser. And by now, I've never seen any browsers display a web content partly, not because they don't want, but because they can't. A browsing context (web browser, iframe...) which is a kind of standard defined by the W3C, must display a whole content of a web page

Answer (score 0):

Here is an iframe tag :

```
<iframe src="jsfiddle.com" ></iframe>
```

I used this css rule on it :

```
iframe{
border: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;

}
```

If the iframe content seems to vary, you can manage the height directly with jquery, just like this:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
iframe.height = iframe.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight+10;
});
```

And all will work great !

Note :

you can adjust the width and the height (even iframe.height) according to your need (take the tag parent of the iframe into account). But if you just want to hide the border, the border rule inside the css would be enough.

https://jsfiddle.net/edgarkamdem/6n2k4m3e/3/

Comment: thanks! What I'm really looking to do is to be able to target specific elements within the iframe (or other container if I use another method). Any thoughts on how I could do that?

Comment: Ah! OK, I see, you can't ! In fact, iframe is an html element and a formalised specification defined by the W3C (https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/iframe.html) . and in the W3C documentation, we can read that iframe is a nested browsing context (https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/browsers.html)  just a little bit like browser. And by now, I've never seen any browsers display a web content partly, not because they don't want, but because they can't. A browsing context (web browser, iframe...) which is a kind of standard defined by the W3C, must display a whole content of a web page.